# Group lasso for generalized linear models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lasso, regularization, fused-lasso

Are there any references on using (sparse) group Lasso for GLMs? I am interested in Gamma GLMs. Any examples of software to perform this would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2408) can both be used for reference of group LASSO in GLMs and mentions an implementation in R in the `grplasso` package, comparing it to the lasso in `glmnet`. If you are unfamiliar with `glmnet`, I highly recommend reading up on it as it is a very versatile package for regularization which also includes built in cross-validation functions.

Comment: `glmnet` doesn't do group LASSO, `grplasso` does

Comment: You may also be interested in the book, [Statistical Learning With Sparsity](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity_files/SLS_corrected_1.4.16.pdf)